# There is no started application when trying to use beforeAll in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

in my test class I want to do something before all the tests begin, so I did something like this:

```
class ApplicationSpec extends FreeSpec with OneServerPerSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    doSomething()
  }

  "Application Test" - {
    "first test" in {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

but I get an error:

> Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - There is
>   no started application java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

it only works if i try to use doSomething() inside the tests...

how can i fix this?

thanks!

Comment: were you able to try out my solution?

Comment: yes man, just reviewed it and it solved the problem and your explanation was great, thanks! @SumeetSharma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming `doSomething()` performs some operation that is dependent on application state.

Try this:

```
class ApplicationSpec extends FreeSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with OneServerPerSuite{

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    doSomething()
  }

  "Application Test" - {
    "first test" in {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

The problem is you are possibly `mixin linearization in wrong order`. 
By `mixin` OneSerPerSuite before BeforeAndAfterAll, the order in which the `super.run()` is called is reversed, leading to `beforeAll()` being called before Application start.

From the git repo of the two projects:

```
 //BeforeAndAfterAll
 abstract override def run(testName: Option[String], args: Args): Status = {
    if (!args.runTestInNewInstance && (expectedTestCount(args.filter) > 0 || invokeBeforeAllAndAfterAllEvenIfNoTestsAreExpected))
      beforeAll()

    val (runStatus, thrownException) =
      try {
        (super.run(testName, args), None)
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => (FailedStatus, Some(e))
      }
    ...
   }


    //OneServerPerSuite
    abstract override def run(testName: Option[String], args: Args): Status = {
    val testServer = TestServer(port, app)
    testServer.start()
    try {
      val newConfigMap = args.configMap + ("org.scalatestplus.play.app" -> app) + ("org.scalatestplus.play.port" -> port)
      val newArgs = args.copy(configMap = newConfigMap)
      val status = super.run(testName, newArgs)
      status.whenCompleted { _ => testServer.stop() }
      status
    } catch { // In case the suite aborts, ensure the server is stopped
      case ex: Throwable =>
        testServer.stop()
        throw ex
    }
  }
```

So by putting the `OneServerPerSuite` trait in the end, it will `first initialize the application`, then call `super.run()` which will call the `run` method inside `BeforeAndAfterAll` which will execute `beforeAll()` and then invoke `super.run()` of `FreeSpec` which will execute the tests.